# How to find the polyline's ID connecting two points in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, line

I have an ArcMap (*.mxd) file with several layers including a point layer and a polyline layer.

The points are connected by polylines in the polyline layer, and I wish to know how to list the connectivity  relation in a table?

For example, if point 1 and 2 are connected by polyline 105, then the relevant row in the resulting table looks something like "1    2    105".

Comment: I am interested to see answers to your Question.  I suspect you will need to have a Geometric Network in place but I am not aware of a tool/script to read that and create the table that you seek.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to gain the depicted table, though quite clumsy.

Since any polyline of the given polyline layer connects with two points (at the start and the end respectively) of the point layer, I used the join function provided by ArcMap which appends the point layer's fields to the polyline layer. On the join Dialog, I chosed the Minimum and Maximum checkboxes to record the minimal and maximal IDs of the related points. Since there are only two points connecting each polyline, the resulting table contained what I need.